# PID returned from GetWindowThreadProcessId call doesn't match the PID from TaskManager

Tags: go, winapi

I'm trying to get the PID of active foreground window on windows 10 using Go.

first I call this function and get handle:

```
func GetForegroundWindow() uintptr {
    us32 := syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    prc := us32.MustFindProc("GetForegroundWindow")
    ret, _, _ := prc.Call()
    return ret
}
```

later using the handle returned from the function above, I'm calling this function:

```
func GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd uintptr) uintptr {
    us32 := syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    prc := us32.MustFindProc("GetWindowThreadProcessId")
    ret, _, err := prc.Call(hwnd, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&hwnd)))
    fmt.Println("ProcessId: ", ret, " Error: ", err)
    return ret
}
```

When I cross check the returned PID by running tasklist /fi "pid eq returnedPid" it doesn't match any process.

And the call to OpenProcess is always returning 0, with an error saying "The parameter is incorrect."

```
func GetOpenProcess(pid uintptr) {
    kernel32 := syscall.MustLoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    proc := kernel32.MustFindProc("OpenProcess")
    res, _, err := proc.Call(ptr(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS|PROCESS_QUERY_INFO), ptr(true), ptr(pid))
    fmt.Println("OpenProcess: result:", res, " Error:", err)
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You likely don't need `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`, but the problem would likely seem to be that you passed the wrong PID.

Comment: Do you mean to say the pid returned from GetWindowThreadProcessId could be wrong?

Comment: That would be the obvious conclusion

Comment: [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) returns the process ID into a `DWORD` whose address you pass into the call. You seem to be passing a pointer to `hwnd`. That, at least, reads wrong. And you never seem to be reading the value back. Instead, you appear to be printing the **thread** ID, tagged as `"ProcessId:"`.

Comment: @IInspectable hey thanks alot for pointing out, able to get right process Id now. Thanks again

Comment: Feel free to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) when you have understood the issue, and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue based on the comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable

What I was doing wrong was, trying to use the value returned from syscall and I was passing a pointer to the window handle as a second parameter to GetWindowThreadProcessId() function, which was also wrong. Instead, **to get Active Window process Id I had to pass a new pointer(second argument) and use the value from that pointer after the function returns instead of the returned value**. Because, the GetWindowThreadProcessId function writes the PID to that location which the second parameter points to.

Please find the modified Code below:

```
func GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd uintptr) uintptr {
    var prcsId uintptr = 0
    us32 := syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    prc := us32.MustFindProc("GetWindowThreadProcessId")
    ret, _, err := prc.Call(hwnd, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&prcsId)))
    log.Println("ProcessId: ", prcsId, "ret", ret, " Message: ", err)
    return prcsId
}
```

log of the function:
2020/04/18 14:31:21 ProcessId:  **13652** ret 13644  Message:  The operation completed successfully.

[image]